# Assembly multiply/divide menu

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, dos

I'm very new to assembly programming, mostly just trying to learn from youtube videos and the "assembly language for x86 processors" pdf. the program is no where near completion now, but I'm already getting 3 errors I can't figure out.

1. invalid character in file (line 1)
2. invalid instruction operands (lines 27,46,26)
3. Symbol type conflict (line 15)

   ```
   .model small
   .data
   message db "Please enter a for mutiplication or b for division $"
   message2 db " Enter the first number $"
   message3 db " Enter the second number $"
   message4 db " * $"
   message5 db " / $"
   message6 db " = $"

   .code
   main proc
   mov ax, seg message
   mov ds, ax
   mov dx, offset message
   mov ah, 9h
   int 21h

   mov ah, 1h ;input stored in al
   int 21h

   mov bl, al ; menu selection input stored in bl so al can be used freely

   mov ah, seg message2
   mov ds, ah
   mov dx, offset message2
   mov ah, 9h
   int 21h

   mov ah, 1h; input stored in al
   int 21h

   mov cl, al ; first number input stored in cl so al can be used freely

   mov dl, bl
   mov ah, 2h
   int 21h

   mov dl, al ;second number imput stored in dl so al can be used again

   sub cl, 30h ;convert characters to decimal
   sub dl, 30h

   mov ax, cl ;preform division
   div dl

   mov al, cl ;preform multiplication
   mul dl


   add cl, 30h ; convert decimal back to the characters
   add dl, 30h



   main endp

    end main
   ```

eventually I want to limit the range of inputs to 1-100 and I'd appreciate any tips on how to do that also, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Remove the lines that try to get the segment from `message`. At the top of your code you can set _DS_ once with `mov ax, @data` `mov ds, ax`.

Comment: The line `mov ax, cl` is not allowed. _CL_ is an 8 bit register and _AX_ is a 16-bit register.

Comment: When I use '@data' now its giving me a new error "undefined symbol: Dgroup" on the line with the '@data'. What am i missing here? do i need to use IsDefined?

Comment: What are you using to assemble this? What is your linker? Almost sounds like your linker may not understand 16-bit.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft visual studio i opened a win32 project with build customization set to masm

Comment: You can't generate 16-bit code with the assembler and linker that comes with Visual Studio. You have to obtain a version of MASM that can generate 16-bit objects and you need a 16-bit linker.

Comment: well that explains a lot, do you have any suggestions of something i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce here the errors 1) and 3). Maybe they are "gone" with copying. Delete the lines in the source and type them again.

"error A2070:invalid instruction operands":

1) Lines 27 and 26:

```
mov ah, seg message2
mov ds, ah
```

A segment is a 16-bit value. You cannot load it into an 8-bit register (`AH`). Furthermore, you cannot copy an 8-bit register (`AH`) to a 16-bit register (`DS`). Change the lines to:

```
mov ax, seg message2
mov ds, ax
```

2) Line 46:

```
mov ax, cl ;preform division
div dl
```

You cannot copy an 8-bit register (`CL`) to a 16-bit-register (`AX`). There are special instructions to perform such a thing: `MOVZX` & `MOVSX`. The first instruction treats the 8-bit register as an unsigned integer, the second as signed integer. Change the lines to:

```
movzx ax, cl ;preform division
div dl
```

An "ancient" 8086 way is:

```
xor ch, ch ; set CH (the upper part of CX) to null
mov ax, cx ;preform division
div dl
```

Comment: God, I feel silly. thanks for the help, I had thought about using movzx or movsx when planning this and completely forgot.

Comment: @rkhb I see. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: If you're going to xor-zero, do `xor ax,ax` / `mov al, cl`.  That will [cause partial-register stalls / slowdowns on fewer CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) than zeroing `ch` and then reading `cx`.  It's the same code size and should perform identically on real 8086.  (On a modern CPU, xor-zeroing `eax` before writing `al` would be much better than only `ax`)